# PHP session info malfunction

Tags: php, session

I'm using PHP sessions in order to store info about the type of source that my visitors came from. That sourch can be either `One` , `Two` or `Other`, depends on their `a` parameter, if set, once they arrive to the website.

These visitors always arrive to a page like `a.php`, that always have the following code pattern:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Store the first Source visitor arrived from, in session:

if (empty($_SESSION['source'])) {

   if(isset($_GET['a']));

    switch ($_GET['a']) {

       case "1":
        $_SESSION['source'] = "One";
        break;

      case "2":
        $_SESSION['source'] = "Two";
        break;

      default:
        $_SESSION['source'] = "Other";
}
}
?>
```

As far as I understand, this code doesn't leave an option for `$_SESSION['source']` to ever remain empty.

Then, inside `a.php`, I have a link to `b.php`, which processes the information in that session variable, and stores it in some database, using this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$src=$_SESSION['source']; // Get source from session

// some code to store $src value in a datbase //

?>
```

When I'm looking at the database, this configuration has been working ever since I've implmented it about a month ago, as each visitor always had some value out of those 3 possible source values.

However, yesterday, I noticed a malfunction, as 3 different visitors (out of 15 who went to `b.php`, with 3 different User agents, did not have ANY value recorded for their source.

I suppose that this problem can stem only due to some kind of information loss, maybe when moving from `a.php` to `b.php`, but I have no idea how is it possible all of the sudden, as I didn't change nothing in the code, and it has worked over 1,000 times, and suddenly in one day, it didn't work for 20% of the visitors.

I am on a VPS server, and every day I get some kind of Cron Daemon email with a list of verifications / updates that are being made, perhaps yesterday it made some automatic change to way sessions work?

Here is my current `PHP.INI` configuration:

[image]

In my `/tmp` folder I do see the current sessions getting stored correctly with all info, so not sure how to further investigate the problem. The malfunctioning sessions aleady got deleted from the folder.

Comment: you needs some curlys after this.. `if(isset($_GET['a']));`

Comment: It is likely the b.php was visited directly without the session ever being set.

Comment: `b.php` can never be visited directly, as I restricted access to it only to users who access it with a POST action. direct access will yield 405 error. furthermore, the database is triggered to create a record only for users who accessed it with a POST. and the said 3 users were real users, not bots. Also, I see in my Raw access logs that these users did visit `a.php`, as the database records their IP number.

Comment: Is the domain consistent between the `a.php` and `b.php` for the request with the problem? e.g. a user might visit `http://www.example.com/a.php`, which links to `http://example.com/b.php`, with different domains (www vs. no-www), which would affect the session.

Comment: yes it is consistent, the link path is relative (`/b.php`) and not absolute.